# Grequests failing for a long list of urls despite size

Tags: python, post, get, grequests

I had a task of form:

```
1)send an http get to url based on a parameter
2)Modify the response based on the same parameter
3)send an http post to url based on the same parameter
```

I used `grequests` to accomplish this.Now for `55 urls` it worked fine.
Then i tried for `34000` .It failed with 
`Connection aborted.', gaierror(8, 'nodename nor servname provided, or not known')) for request <grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x1bda93610>`.

Then i tried with `size` parameter in `grequests.map` and tried with `size`=`64`.Got the same error.
Now is there anything else i can do or i need to use something else and `grequests` is not suitable for this task.